# Como alinhando conteúdo em <td>?

Tags: html, css

Como eu faço para alinhar o conteúdo da `<td>` dentro da minha tabela?

Sei que para alinha horizontalmente utilizo `text-align: center; //text-aling está errado`.

Quero que fique igual a `Teste` e `Armas`.

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="">
       <thead>
             <tr>
                <th>Icone</th>
                <th>Nome</th>
                <th>Categoria</th>
                <th>Tipo</th>
                <th>Level</th>
                <th>Preço</th>
            </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
             <tr>
             <td style="text-align: center;"><img src=""></td>
             <td style="text-align: center;"></td>
             <td style="text-align: center;"></td>
             <td style="text-align: center;"></td>
             <td style="text-align: center;"></td>
             <td style="text-align: center;"></td>
             </tr>
     </tbody>
</table>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, abaixo está o código:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="">
       <thead>
             <tr>
                <th>Icone</th>
                <th>Nome</th>
                <th>Categoria</th>
                <th>Tipo</th>
                <th>Level</th>
                <th>Preço</th>
            </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
             <tr>
             <td style="text-align: center;"><img src="https://www.google.com.br/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"></td>
             <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align:middle !important">teste</td>
             <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align:middle !important">teste</td>
             <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align:middle !important">teste</td>
             <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align:middle !important">teste</td>
             <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align:middle !important"></td>
             </tr>
     </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Faz um estilo para essa tabela tipo

```
    table tr{
       text-align: center;
    }
```

Comment: é assim que esta atualmente.

Answer (score 1):

O bom de tabelas é que dá para alinhar verticalmente bem fácil.

Basta usar `vertical-align: middle`

Comment: Não foi, continua do mesmo jeito da imagem.

Comment: pode mandar o html dessa tabela? você quer que ele fique centralizado horizontal e verticalmente?

Comment: Tente usar o atributo valign=middle então conforme está aqui https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_valign.asp

Comment: Pergunta alterada e colocado o html.

Comment: Está faltando <tr> nesta tabela

Comment: esqueci de digitar

Comment: tentou usar o atributo valign?

Comment: Sim continua a mesma coisa.

Comment: Qual o resultado que você espera desta tabela, eu ainda não entendi direito o que você quer.

Comment: Ok consegui, basta colocar !important na frente

Comment: Editei a pergunta para melhorar entendimento.

Comment: Como assim colocar !important na frente?

Comment: adicionei o código em uma resposta :-)

Comment: Agora entendi por que precisava colocar o !important?

Comment: Porque estamos modificando o comportando do Bootstrap, o !important faz com que você force que o estilo mais próximo do elemento seja o estilo considerado pelo browser.

Comment: Entendo agora não fazia ideia que tinha este tipo de prioridade. Obrigado.

Comment: Não é uma boa pratica no entanto! apenas resolve seu problema, mas esse não é o melhor caminho, ok? o certo é verificar onde está sendo forçado esse alinhamento no topo e tentar fazer ajustes nesta classe ou talvez fazer um "override" dessa classe.